# How to add information to a field from a function created in a view?

Tags: python, django

How would I take a value from a view function and put it in a model field? For example, let’s say I did a view that adds two numbers together. How would take that value and add it to the field of a model every time an instance of that model is created? Or is there another way of doing this that I’m not seeing.

I have a function that takes the user's IP and displays the city and region they are in. I was wondering how I could put that information in a model field every time an instance of that model is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about `get_context_data()` which is a method that allows you to pass data to the template.
For example, here is the code from official docs:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Book, Publisher

class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

You can then access that context in your template:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    <p>{{ book.name }}</p>
```

In your example you would pass the IP to the template or the form depending on what you are trying to do.
Here are official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) that explain it